# Как в проекте CppWinRT преобразовать указатель byte* к интерфейсу IBuffer

Tags: c++, winrt

Я использую компонент с++ dll с использованием пакета [Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT/),
в котором хочу выполнить преобразование byte* к Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer
без излишней "аллокаци и копирования".
[За основу я взял NativeBuffer из поста](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520335/how-to-wrap-a-char-buffer-in-a-winrt-ibuffer-in-c)

В частности, использую следующий код:

```
MediaStreamSample SimpleMath::MakeMediaStreamSample(IMemoryBufferReference bufferReference, unsigned int nNumberOfBytes, TimeSpan timestamp, TimeSpan duration)
{
    auto memoryBufferByteAccess = 
        bufferReference.as<IMemoryBufferByteAccess>();

    BYTE* data;
    UINT32 capacity;
    memoryBufferByteAccess->GetBuffer(&data, &capacity);

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<NativeBuffer> nativeBuffer;
    Microsoft::WRL::Details::MakeAndInitialize<NativeBuffer>(&nativeBuffer, (byte*)data, nNumberOfBytes);

    // origin in WRL
    //Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ buffer = reinterpret_cast<Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^>(nativeBuffer.Get());

    // variant1 
    // error C2440: reinterpret_cast: невозможно преобразовать "winrt::implements<D,winrt::SimpleMathComponent::SimpleMath>::IInspectable *" в "winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer"
    auto iinspectable = (IInspectable*)reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(nativeBuffer.Get());
    auto buffer = reinterpret_cast<Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer>(iinspectable);

    auto mediaStreamSample =
        MediaStreamSample::CreateFromBuffer(buffer, timestamp);

    mediaStreamSample.Duration(duration);

    return
        mediaStreamSample;
}
```

Это приводит к ошибке компиляции

error C2440: reinterpret_cast: невозможно преобразовать "winrt::implements<D,winrt::SimpleMathComponent::SimpleMath>::IInspectable *" в "winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После различных изысканий я остановился на следующем варианте:

```
MediaStreamSample MakeMediaStreamSample(IMemoryBufferReference bufferReference, unsigned int nNumberOfBytes, TimeSpan timestamp, TimeSpan duration)
{
    auto memoryBufferByteAccess =
        bufferReference.as<IMemoryBufferByteAccess>();

    BYTE* data;
    UINT32 capacity;
    memoryBufferByteAccess->GetBuffer(&data, &capacity);

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<NativeBuffer> nativeBuffer;
    Microsoft::WRL::Details::MakeAndInitialize<NativeBuffer>(&nativeBuffer, (byte*)data, nNumberOfBytes);

    // origin in WRL
    //Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ buffer = reinterpret_cast<Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^>(nativeBuffer.Get());

    auto buffer = 
        winrt::impl::wrap_as_result<IBuffer>(nativeBuffer.Get());

    auto mediaStreamSample =
        MediaStreamSample::CreateFromBuffer(buffer, timestamp);

    mediaStreamSample.Duration(duration);

    return
        mediaStreamSample;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В этой ситуации необходимо создавать новый буфер в памяти и копировать содержимое в него, например вызывая `Windows::Storage::Streams::Buffer::CreateCopyFromMemoryBuffer`, как бы этого не хотелось. Это необходимо сделать, так как иначе NativeBuffer будет содержать указатель, с временем жизни блока памяти, на который тот указывает, не привязанным к счетчику ссылок данного объекта.

Comment: В вопросе четко указано, что конвертация нужна без дополнительной "аллокации". "Счетчик ссылок" совершенно меня не интересует т.к. входной пермеаметр "IMemoryBufferReference bufferReference" это элемент из пула который заранее "аллоцирован". Т.е. для упрощения можно считать, что на весь период "жизненного цикла приложения" создается пул с заранее распределенной памятью условно под 100 элементов "IMemoryBufferReference bufferReference" память каждого из которого периодически используется для создания MediaStreamSample, и дополнительное "алоцирование+перекопирование" недопустимо.

Comment: Также отмечу, что конвертация корректно работает в UWP (библиотека dll UWP). Т.е. нужен аналог указанной конвертации в новом wrt\c++ по аналогии с WRL. Вариант с "перекопированнием" понятен/известен/мало интересен (крайний случай).

Comment: @dex Не, ну если надо просто получить интерфейс IBuffer, то достаточно будет сделать что-то типа `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer> p{nativeBuffer}`, умный указатель там сам вызовет что нужно, а дикие касты не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо за последний комментарий - это привело меня к варианту: auto buffer = winrt::impl::wrap_as_result<IBuffer>(nativeBuffer.Get());